# SVG animation without using any external library

Tags: svg

Is it possible to do the blinking eye effect from this SVG? If possible using CSS only.

```html
<div style="background: black;padding: 20px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="134.527" height="134.502" viewBox="0 0 134.527 134.502">
     <defs>
       <clipPath id="clip-path">
         <rect id="Rectangle_527" data-name="Rectangle 527" width="134.527" height="134.502" fill="none"/>
       </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g id="Group_441" data-name="Group 441" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
       <path id="Path_1157" data-name="Path 1157" d="M134.31,66.626A77.276,77.276,0,0,1,.3,66.817" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
       <circle id="Ellipse_25" data-name="Ellipse 25" cx="67.001" cy="67.001" r="67.001" transform="translate(0.25 0.25)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
       <path id="Path_1158" data-name="Path 1158" d="M.336,66.626a77.275,77.275,0,0,1,133.889.1" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
       <path id="Path_1159" data-name="Path 1159" d="M67.122,95.866a28.7,28.7,0,1,1,11.26-2.276,28.932,28.932,0,0,1-11.26,2.276m0-44.465h0c-1.232,4.832-2.378,8.063-4.592,10.276s-5.445,3.359-10.277,4.59c4.833,1.232,8.064,2.38,10.277,4.593s3.36,5.444,4.592,10.277c1.231-4.832,2.378-8.063,4.59-10.277s5.444-3.36,10.277-4.593c-4.833-1.231-8.064-2.378-10.277-4.59s-3.359-5.445-4.59-10.276" fill="#9bd698"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: What means blinking in your vision?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SVG animation with SMIL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL). Here, the [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) element inside the path to animate the d attribute of the path.

```html
<div style="background: black;padding: 20px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="130" height="130" viewBox="0 0 122 122">
    <g transform="translate(1 1)">
      <path transform="translate(60 60)" d="M 0 23.7 a 23 23 90 1 1 9 -1.8 a 23.1 23.1 90 0 1 -9 1.8 m 0 -35.6 h 0 c -1 3.9 -1.9 6.5 -3.7 8.2 s -4.4 2.7 -8.2 3.7 c 3.9 1 6.5 1.9 8.2 3.7 s 2.7 4.4 3.7 8.2 c 1 -3.9 1.9 -6.5 3.7 -8.2 s 4.4 -2.7 8.2 -3.7 c -3.9 -1 -6.5 -1.9 -8.2 -3.7 s -2.7 -4.4 -3.7 -8.2" fill="#9bd698"/>
      <path d="M 120 60 Q 60 110 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 0 120 60 Z" fill="#000"
        stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1">
        <animate attributeName="d" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" values="
        M 120 60 Q 60 110 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 0 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 110 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 0 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 60 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 0 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 60 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 0 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 110 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 0 120 60 Z"
        keyTimes="0;0.1; 0.33;0.8;1" dur="4s" />
      </path>
      <path d="M 120 60 Q 60 10 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 1 120 60 Z" fill="#000"
        stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1">
        <animate attributeName="d" repeatCount="indefinite" values="
        M 120 60 Q 60 10 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 1 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 10 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 1 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 60 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 1 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 60 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 1 120 60 Z;
        M 120 60 Q 60 10 0 60 A 1 1 0 0 1 120 60 Z"
        keyTimes="0;0.1;0.33;0.8;1" dur="4s" />
      </path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, SVG SMIL animation is probably the best cross-browser solution - as suggested by **[chrwahl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76376943/svg-animation-without-using-any-external-library#76384381)**.

### Future approach: morph paths via css `path()`

This is currently (2023) **not supported in safari.**
However, we might see better support in the next years.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

.eyelids {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

#eyelid__top {
  animation: closeEye1 1s infinite forwards;
}

#eyelid__bottom {
  animation: closeEye2 1s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes closeEye1 {
  0% {
    d: path("M0 67.25 A 67.25 67.25 0 0 1 134.5 67.25A 77 77 0 0 0 0 67.25 z");
  }
  20% {
    d: path("M0 67.25 A 67.25 67.25 0 0 1 134.5 67.25A 77 0 0 0 0 0 67.25 z");
  }
  40% {
    d: path("M0 67.25 A 67.25 67.25 0 0 1 134.5 67.25A 77 77 0 0 0 0 67.25 z");
  }
}

@keyframes closeEye2 {
  0% {
    d: path("M0 67.25 A 67.25 67.25 0 0 0 134.5 67.25 A 77 77 0 0 1 0 67.25 z ");
  }
  20% {
    d: path("M0 67.25 A 67.25 67.25 0 0 0 134.5 67.25 A 77 0 0 0 1 0 67.25 z ");
  }
  40% {
    d: path("M0 67.25 A 67.25 67.25 0 0 0 134.5 67.25 A 77 77 0 0 1 0 67.25 z ");
  }
}

.active {
  fill: red
}


/*
#eyelid__top{
  d: path("M 0 67.25 C 0 15.48 56.04 -16.87 100.88 9.01 C 121.68 21.02 134.5 43.22 134.5 67.25 C 105.63 15.48 31.55 14.38 1.15 65.26 C 0.75 65.92 0.37 66.58 0 67.25 Z")
}

#eyelid__top.active{
  d: path("M 0 67.25 C 0 15.48 56.04 -16.87 100.88 9.01 C 121.68 21.02 134.5 43.22 134.5 67.25 C 105.63 119.02 31.55 120.12 1.15 69.24 C 0.75 68.58 0.37 67.92 0 67.25 Z");
}

#eyelid__bottom{
  d: path("M 0 67.25C 0 119.02 56.04 151.37 100.88 125.49C 121.68 113.48 134.5 91.28 134.5 67.25C 105.63 119.02 31.55 120.12 1.15 69.24C 0.75 68.58 0.37 67.92 0 67.25Z")
}

#eyelid__bottom.active{
  d: path("M0 67.25C0 119.02 56.04 151.37 100.88 125.49C121.68 113.48 134.5 91.28 134.5 67.25C105.63 53.8 31.55 53.52 1.15 66.73C0.75 66.9 0.37 67.08 0 67.25Z");
}

*/


/*
svg:hover
#eyelid__top{
  d: path("M 0 67.25 C 0 15.48 56.04 -16.87 100.88 9.01 C 121.68 21.02 134.5 43.22 134.5 67.25 C 105.63 119.02 31.55 120.12 1.15 69.24 C 0.75 68.58 0.37 67.92 0 67.25 Z");
}

svg:hover
#eyelid__bottom{
  d: path("M0 67.25C0 119.02 56.04 151.37 100.88 125.49C121.68 113.48 134.5 91.28 134.5 67.25C105.63 53.8 31.55 53.52 1.15 66.73C0.75 66.9 0.37 67.08 0 67.25Z");
}
*/
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="134.527" height="134.502" viewBox="0 0 134.5 134.5">

    <path id="pupil" d="M 67.1 95.9 a 28.7 28.7 0 1 1 11.3 -2.3 a 28.9 28.9 0 0 1 -11.3 2.3z 
m 0 -44.5 h 0 c -1.2 4.8 -2.4 8.1 -4.6 10.3 s -5.4 3.4 -10.3 4.6 c 4.8 1.2 8.1 2.4 10.3 4.6 s 3.4 5.4 4.6 10.3 c 1.2 -4.8 2.4 -8.1 4.6 -10.3 s 5.4 -3.4 10.3 -4.6 c -4.8 -1.2 -8.1 -2.4 -10.3 -4.6 s -3.4 -5.4 -4.6 -10.3z" fill="#9bd698" />

<path id="eyelid__top" class="eyelids" d="
M0 67.25 
A 67.25 67.25 0 0 1 134.5 67.25
A 77 77 0 0 0 0 67.25 z"  />
  

<path class="eyelids" id="eyelid__bottom" d="
M0 67.25 
A 67.25 67.25 0 0 0 134.5 67.25 
A 77 77 0 0 1 0 67.25 z                                                    
"  />

</svg>
```

### Path compatibility

For shape "morphing" interpolation both paths need to be perfectly compatible i.e:

- have the exact same number of commands
- use the same command types (shorthands like `V`, `H`, `S` or `T` won't work if their correspondend path uses "longhand" equivalents like `L`,`C` or `Q`
- correspondent path segments can't switch between relative and absolute commands
- long arc and sweep flag in **Arc commands**: These values are boolean and can only be 1 or 0:

So we can't switch these parameters during interpolation. E.g:

```
M0 50 A 50 50 0 0 0 100 50
```

to

```
M0 50 A 50 50 0 1 1 100 50
```

can't be transitioned/interpolated.

The same rules apply to SVG SMIL animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can often get nice effects with little tricks, like stretching or shrinking elements. In this case, I understand that you want to close the *lids* and make the *pupil* disappear. A simple way to close the lids is to shrink them vertically towards the center. But this would not be enough. You also need to shrink an additional element that clips the pupil, so that it disappears as the lids close. In this example, I have added a `clipPath` (`#cPath_1157`) that is identical to that of the lids (more on that below) and is animated with the same parameters:

```css
.blink{
  animation: frombot 0.3s linear 1s 10;
  transform-origin: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes frombot{
  
  to{
    transform: scaleY(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background: black;padding: 20px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="134.527" height="134.502" viewBox="0 0 134.527 134.502">
     <defs>
       <clipPath id="clip-path">
         <rect id="Rectangle_527" data-name="Rectangle 527" width="134.527" height="134.502" fill="none"/>
       </clipPath>
       <clipPath id="bl1" class="blink">
         <path id="cPath_1157" class="blink" data-name="PathC1157" d="M134.31,66.626A77.276,77.276,0,0,1,.3,66.817A77.276,77.276,0,0,1,134.31,66.626Z" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
       </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g id="Group_441" data-name="Group 441" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
       <path id="Path_1157" class="blink" data-name="Path 1157" d="M134.31,66.626A77.276,77.276,0,0,1,.3,66.817A77.276,77.276,0,0,1,134.31,66.626Z" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
       <circle id="Ellipse_25" data-name="Ellipse 25" cx="67.001" cy="67.001" r="67.001" transform="translate(0.25 0.25)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1"/>
       
       <path id="Path_1159" clip-path="url(#bl1)" data-name="Path 1159" d="M67.122,95.866a28.7,28.7,0,1,1,11.26-2.276,28.932,28.932,0,0,1-11.26,2.276m0-44.465h0c-1.232,4.832-2.378,8.063-4.592,10.276s-5.445,3.359-10.277,4.59c4.833,1.232,8.064,2.38,10.277,4.593s3.36,5.444,4.592,10.277c1.231-4.832,2.378-8.063,4.59-10.277s5.444-3.36,10.277-4.593c-4.833-1.231-8.064-2.378-10.277-4.59s-3.359-5.445-4.59-10.276" fill="#9bd698"/>
      </g>
  
    </svg>
    </div>
```

A couple of points:

- There is a small discrepancy between the lids and the clipPath. It is present in all the browsers. This suggests that there is a detail in the implementation of clip-path that I have not taken into account.
- I have also changed the code for the lids. You had two paths and I have fused them into one, as it greatly simplifies the animation.